# Dynamic Actions: Send an Email

Tags: lightning-app-builder, dynamic-actions

I have been reading about Dynamic Actions, and it is setup in the org I am working in.  When I try and use it, it shows me a long list of actions I can select, but does not show Send Email for some reason.  Is this something that's not supported at this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Email action is supported and displays only in Salesforce mobile app.

[image]

[Dynamic Actions](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_lex_dynamic_actions_highlights_panel.htm) is available in Beta version and this feature might be rolled out in near future.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looks to be. I can't find any docs to call out this limitation. However, if you look at the [Quick Actions doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_quick_action.htm), you'll see there's an endpoint to get a list of your custom quick actions per object

`/v50.0/actions/custom/quickAction/Opportunity`

This only returns *non-SendEmail* custom Quick Actions which is curious.

None of this is definitive evidence, but I can at least say I do not get an option to select email-actions in the dynamic actions and the above seems to indicate this could be by design and simply not called out.

Answer (score 3):

This is because Send Email quick action doesn't show up in the highlights panel where all buttons are located. Send Email quick actions are added either under Activity tab or Feed tab. That is why its not visible under dynamic actions as dynamic action feature is applicable for the buttons which are being displayed in hightlights panel.

[image]